# Sandbox clones for other SE sites

Tags: discussion, sandbox, moderators, stackexchange

Can Wordbuilding host other SE sites sandboxes to help users to build good question in that site? I tried the idea of a Sandbox.SE on Area 51 and was not well-received.

https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28019/sandbox-for-all

I wander can traffic be increased to Worldbuilding.SE if other subjects like Physics and Aviation where hosted here as a courtesy?

Can this be tried here as a SE social experiment?

Comment: Side note: the link you have posted lands on "This question was removed from Area 51 Discussions for reasons of moderation."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would argue that we don't really need to increase traffic to Worldbuilding. Worldbuilding SE is getting a fair amount of traffic. It's certainly as active as, if not more so than, both Physics and Aviation.

The community that decides whether they want a question sandbox, and where it is to be hosted, should be the community in question. Nothing is gained by one site imposing a standard onto other sites. Imagine if, say, [Mi Yodeya](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/) was to host a sandbox for us! What are the odds that people posting there would get good advice on what makes a good Worldbuilding SE question, beyond the absolute basics like, say, being able to tell what the question *is*? Now, why would it be any different if it's the other way around?

Also, for example, the issue of whether to create a sandbox was [raised on Writing Meta](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1342/2533) not *all* that long ago. The answer from the community there, judging by the votes, was a resounding ***NO***.

Each site needs to determine on its own whether having a given fraction of the questions posted put on hold is even a problem. To me, putting a question on hold is not really a big deal, if it's warranted; it keeps potentially many more people from wasting their time. If the site's community feels it's a problem having the number of questions closed that they get, then that community needs to decide how to deal with that. A site that aims for *high quality* questions is pretty naturally going to put on hold a larger percentage of the questions that do get posted.

**We should not be imposing our ideas, let alone standards on what makes a good question, on other communities in the network.**

**However,** nothing prevents you from suggesting the idea of a per-site question sandbox on each site's meta, if you think it is worthwhile.

Comment: How can I show the other sites that it does work here and would be a good asset?

Answer (score 8):

SE has several communities, each specialized in a different domain: Aviation, Worldbuilding, History, Interpersonal, just to name a few.

Why is it so? Well, it is just common sense to cluster a community based on the common interests. At home I keep spoons and forks in the same drawer, well separate from screwdrivers and nails. They are all made of metal, but when I need a spoon or a nail I know where to look for.

Likewise here if I am looking for interpersonal skills help, I look in the interpersonal.SE. Why would I ever look into worldbuilding for an interpersonal skill question? Whoever wanders into the worldbuilding meta sandbox is surely skilled in worldbuilding, not necessarily in interpersonal skills. It doesn't matter that sandboxes are in meta; meta discussions are always pertinent to the mother community. Again, separation of interests!

The concept of sandbox is not patented by us, and I doubt anyone would ever raise a complaint about another community using it.

Feel free to ask other meta sites to implement their pertinent sandbox, but have them where they belong. Don't mix what is meant to be separate.

Comment: Not only is it not patented by us, but it's not *original* to us.  We copied the idea from some other SE site (forget which).  Any site *that wants one* can make a sandbox; we don't need to be involved.

Comment: @MonicaCellio Yes but SE could use a junk drawer SE. for questions that do not fit anywhere. A junk drawer can be the most useful drawer in the house.

Comment: @Muze, you are saying worldbuilding should be the junk drawer of SE?

Comment: @L.Dutch No but a off-topic se

Comment: No @Muze, neither SE nor Worldbuilding should be somebody's junk drawer.  SE is about high-quality Q&A -- not junk, not discussion, not forums, not diluting crap that makes the Q&A less useful.  How would you even promote such a site?  "Come to our junk drawer!" -- yeah, experts are gonna *flock* to that, right?  Feel free to pursue your idea somewhere else, but please do not use our meta to do it.

Comment: @MonicaCellio not junk, miscellaneous would be a better word not to be taken out of context.

Comment: You're the one who said "SE could use a junk drawer SE".  That's not going to fly anywhere on SE and it's *certainly* not appropriate for Worldbuilding, so either way this is the wrong place for you to try to have that discussion.

Answer (score 1):

- Ignoring the fact that hosting sandboxes for other sites would be very confusing...
- and ignoring the fact that other sites that don't want sandboxes won't thank us for circumventing their culture and policies...
- and ignoring the fact that SE would probably ask us to cease-and-desist the moment they found out about hosted sandboxes for other Stacks...

We have enough trouble convincing people to help out in our own sandbox, much less convincing people from other stacks to come help out here (or, worse, trying to do it ourselves while trying to meet the unique cultures and policies of those other stacks).

Please remember that while we, the users, are heavily involved with the day-to-day operation of the Stacks we participate in — we don't own any of them and don't have the right to re-create them in our own image.  If you really are interested in a universal sandbox, the best place to ask about it is [Meta.StackExchange.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/).

*I don't believe the response will be much different than you're getting here.*